# How can you adjust for ceiling effects in predicted effectiveness?

Tags: regression

I have a dataset from a trial of a new method to encourage people to vote. The dataset has three variables:

- cond: treatment vs control
- predictive_score: A value from 0 to 100 reflecting how likely someone is to vote based on demographics and vote history, with higher numbers representing larger probability of voting
- voted: Whether or not the person voted in this year's election

I want to find out if the treatment is equally effective at different levels of predictive score. The code below shows that there's a positive effect of the treatment and a negative interaction between treatment and predictive_score. But the latter is probably in large part because as predictive_score gets higher, more people were going to vote anyway so there are fewer people for whom the treatment might have made a difference. Is there a good method for controlling for this influence and checking whether the negative interaction is larger than you'd expect, based on the ceiling effect?

example code:

```
avoting_short <- as.data.frame(structure(list(voted = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                                                      TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                                                      TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                                                      FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                                                      FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
                                                      TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                                                      FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
                                                      FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                                                      FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
                                                      FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                                                      FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), cond = c("treatment", 
                                                                                                        "control", "treatment", "treatment", "control", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", "control", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "control", "treatment", "control", "control", "treatment", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", "control", "control", 
                                                                                                        "control", "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "control", "control", "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "control", "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "treatment", "treatment", "control", "treatment", "control", 
                                                                                                        "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "treatment", "treatment", "control", "treatment", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "treatment", "treatment", "control", "treatment", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "treatment", "treatment", "control", "treatment", "control", 
                                                                                                        "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "control", "control", "treatment", "control", "treatment", "control", 
                                                                                                        "treatment", "control", "treatment", "control", "control", "control", 
                                                                                                        "control", "treatment", "treatment", "control", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "treatment", "control", "control", "treatment", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "control", "control", "control", "control", "treatment", "treatment", 
                                                                                                        "control", "treatment", "control", "treatment", "control"), predictive_score = c(33.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         14.5, 58.5, 41, 77.6, 92.1, 93.6, 88.9, 36.4, 31.3, 70.4, 86.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         87.6, NA, 2.1, 45.5, 88.8, 83.5, 34.4, 91.1, 46.2, 52.9, 45.3, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         NA, 26.4, 63.9, 28, 84.2, 50, 67.9, 88.6, 91.9, 73.4, 88.9, 58.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         82.7, 48.7, 41.3, 7.5, 85.7, 95.6, 50.8, 13.6, 4.4, 90.4, 94.9, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         25.1, 24.3, 6.3, 21.2, 31.3, 88.2, 16.1, 62.9, 32.6, 3.5, 1.9, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         18.3, 40.7, 97.5, 90.6, 19.6, 23, 87.9, 48, 27.4, 90.4, 30.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         95.3, 28.1, 86.4, 93.3, 64.5, 85.3, 60.4, 55.5, 30.6, 59.2, 90.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         60, 48.7, 91.2, 23.7, 85.4, 45.8, 87.5, 92.9, 5.4, 91.9, 18.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         82.3, 90, 84.5, 73.6, 33.5, 16.3, 89.6, 25.3, 46.4, 73.4)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -100L), class = "data.frame"))
aglm_voting <- glm(voted ~ cond*scale(predictive_score, scale=F), data=avoting_short, family="binomial")
summary(glm_voting)
```